# Find a filename in a directory excluding zeros that appear in the beginning of the filename

Tags: linux, find, filenames

I have a directory with file names as " 202.png, 405.png, 0052.png, 04050.png, ......
I need a find command to find filenames excluding zeros that appear in the beginning of the file name.
For example if i have a file with file name 00504.png then when I pass argument 504.png to find command it has to return the filename 00504.png which is actual name of the file in the directory.

Expected output command is

`$ find . -name 504.png`

It has to return the original filename which is 00504.png

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the `find` command's `-name` only supports simple glob matches. However you could use `-regex` to match `504.png` prefixed by zero or more `0` characters:

```
find . -regex '.*/0*504.png'
```

The leading `.*/` is because `-regex` is a full path match.

---

If you don't need a recursive search, then shells such as bash may provide extended globs that allow expressions like `*(0)`

```
printf '%s\n' *(0)504.png
```

Check the documentation for the shell you are using.